# Text not wrapping in span/div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have first time problem like that. Text is not wrapping in span (if I changed it to div too) inside bootstrap col.

CSS word-wrap is not working, i have no idea what to do. Span is display inline-block with width: 100%

This is my structure:

```
<div class="col-4 dropdown-item-container">
  <a class="z-depth-1 dropdown-item" href="#">
     <img class="dropdown-image" src="img/cat8.jpg" />
     <span>System do wykonywania połączeń DOMINO</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And it's looks like that:

[image]

Comment: can you add the css?

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. As we don't know what css are you using or if you are using responsive css and also what screen size are you testing this on.

Comment: Your word wrap needs to be on the container, not the span.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem, in bootstrap class .dropdown-item have set white-space: nowrap;